# Copying Data into Cassandra table

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, spark-cassandra-connector

Can we import/copy multiple files into acassandra table which are having same column name in a table and in files?

COPY table1(timestamp ,temp ,total_load ,designl) FROM 'file1', 'file2' WITH HEADER = 'true';

I tried using above syntax: but its saying 
Improper COPY command.

i mean to to say suppose we have 100's of delimiter files with same columns, and i want to load all files into single cassandra table using single cql query?

is this possible:?

when i tried it using each COPY command for each file to a table it is Over Writing the data?

Please Help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify more tables with the following synax:

```
COPY table1("timestamp", temp, total_load, designl) FROM 'file1, file2' WITH HEADER = 'true';
```

or you can also use wildcards:

```
COPY table1("timestamp", temp, total_load, designl) FROM 'folder/*.csv' WITH HEADER = 'true';
```

Two remarks however:

- Timestamp is a type name in Cassandra, if your column has this name, you need to quote it as I did in the example above.
- If your data is overwritten when executing several copy commands, then it will be overwritten even if you execute a single copy command. If you have several lines for the same PRIMARY KEY, then only the last row will win.